# How to pass values to filter and values to use as a condition with the Filter method of Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to Pass the values [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3] to be removed using the funcion "destroyer" and the values 2, 3 (or even more values ex: 1,3,5.) to be removed from the previous array. Always the first part is an array to remove from and followed by numbers to remove from the array

Here you have the code that I have to solve:

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
  return arr;
}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: Do you want to empty the array? `Remove all the values` means emptying it. Why would you want to return an empty array?

Comment: Sounds like college task...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript array difference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187518/javascript-array-difference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this approach. It uses the [**spread operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) and the [**includes()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) function

**...** - is a spread operator

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...items) {
    return arr.filter(i => !items.includes(i));
}

let arr = destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access all parameters passed to a function using `arguments` variable. Note, this is an array like object but not an array, so you will have to convert it to array. When you do that, your `arr` will be the first value as even that is a part of parameters. You can use `.slice(1)` to get all values from second element.

#### ES5

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = [].slice.call(arguments,1);
  return arr.filter(function(val){
    return args.indexOf(val) < 0
  })
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```

#### ES6

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  var args = Array.from(arguments).slice(1);
  return arr.filter(x=>!args.includes(x));
}

console.log(destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3));
```